# How to print tikzpicture in the right place when using fancyfoot

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I have the following case where I don't know how to correct it and I would like that when using tikz I would like it to print in the correct place, which is the footer.

[image: example figure position footer]

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for custom headers
\usepackage[dvipsnames, x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[L]{Muni NC}
    \fancyfoot[R]{ 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.north)}]
            \draw[Red,line width=5pt,rotate=90] (-3mm,2mm) -- (4mm,2mm);
            \node[anchor=west] at (0mm,0) {\large \bfseries\ttfamily \thepage};
        \end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapte title}
\section{Example section}
\end{document}
```

> can you help me please

Comment: `[baseline={(current bounding box.south)}]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the tikz baseline and the node anchor should be set to `base`.  Add `\hrulefill` command after the left foot to show the alignment.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for custom headers
\usepackage[dvipsnames, x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\footskip}{26.01695pt} %avoid warning 


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
    \fancyfoot[L]{Muni NC\hrulefill}
    \fancyfoot[R]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.base)}]
            \draw[Red,line width=5pt] (0,0) -- (0,7mm);
            \node[anchor=base] at (14pt,0) {\large \bfseries\ttfamily \thepage};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapte title}
\section{Example section}
\end{document}
```

> Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks @Tom, this makes me happy

Comment: Is it possible to center the text?

Comment: @royer Center which text?

Comment: Apologies for the case, I think I'm only going to move the coordinates of the line because the text is already in the correct position.